# Declare variable on unix server

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, scripting

I am trying to login on one of the remote server(Box1) and trying to read one file on remote server(Box1).
That contain the another server(Box2) details, base upon that details I have to come back to the local server and ssh to another server(Box2) for some data crunching. and so on.....

```
    ssh box1.com  << EOF
    if [[ ! -f /home/rakesh/tomar.log ]]
    then
    echo "LOG file not found"
    else
    echo " LOG file present"
    export server_node1= `cat /home/rakesh/tomar.log`
    fi
    EOF

    ssh box2.com << EOF
    if [[ ! -f /home/rakesh/tomar.log ]]
    then
    echo "LOG file not found"
    else
    echo " LOG file present"
    export server_node2= `cat /home/rakesh/tomar.log`
    fi
    EOF
```

but I am not getting value of "server_node1" and "server_node2" on local machine.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have `/home/rakesh` in the `[[ ! -f ]]` but `/home/rt9419` in the `cat`.  Are you really checking the existence of one file and then retrieving another on purpose, or is one of these wrong?

Comment: ooops my bad !!

correcting things.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like `bash -c 'export foo=bar'` cannot declare a variable in the calling shell where you typed this, an `ssh` command cannot declare a variable in the calling shell.  You will have to refactor so that the calling shell receives the information and knows what to do with it.

I agree with the comment that storing a log file in a variable is probably not a sane, or at least elegant, thing to do, but the easy way to do what you are attempting is to put the `ssh` inside the assignment.

```
server_node1=$(ssh box1.com cat tomar.log)
server_node2=$(ssh box2.com cat tomar.log)
```

A few notes and amplifications:

- The remote shell will run in your home directory, so I took it out (on the assumption that `/home/rt9419` is *your* home directory, obviously).
- In case of an error in the `cat` command, the exit code of `ssh` will be the error code from `cat`, and the error message on standard error will be visible on your standard error, so the `echo` seemed quite superfluous.  (If you want a custom message, `variable=$(ssh whatever) || echo "Custom message" >&2` would do that.  Note the redirection to standard error; it doesn't seem to matter here, but it's good form.)
- If you really wanted to, you could run an arbitrarily complex command in the `ssh`; as outlined above, it didn't seem necessary here, but you could do `assigment=$(ssh remote 'if [[ things ]]; then for variable in $(complex commands to drive a loop); do : etc etc; done; fi; more </dev/null; exit "$variable"')` or whatever.

As further comments on your original attempt,

- The backticks in the here document in your attempt would be evaluated by your *local* shell before the `ssh` command even ran.  There are separate questions about how to fix that; see e.g. [How have both local and remote variable inside an SSH command.](//stackoverflow.com/questions/13826149/how-have-both-local-and-remote-variable-inside-an-ssh-command) but in short, unless you absolutely require the local shell to be able to modify the commands you send, probably put them in single quotes, like I did in the silly complex `ssh` example above.
- The function of `export` is to make variables visible to *child* processes.  There is no way to affect the environment of a parent process (short of having it cooperate and/or coordinate the change, as in the code above).  As an example to illustrate the difference, if you set `PERL5LIB` to a directory with Perl libraries, but fail to `export` it, the Perl process you start will not see the variable; it is only visible to the current shell.  When you `export` it, any Perl process you start as a child of this shell will also see this variable and the value you assigned.  In other words, you `export` variables which are not private to the current shell (and don't `export` private ones; aside from making sure they are private, this saves the amount of memory which needs to be copied between processes), but that still only makes them visible to children, by the design of the U*x process architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You should get back the file from `box1`and `box2` with an `scp`:

```
scp box1.com:/home/rt9419/tomar.log ~/tomar1.log
#then you can cat!
export server_node1=`cat ~/tomar1.log`
```

idem with `box2`

```
scp box2.com:/home/rt9419/tomar.log ~/tomar2.log
#then you can cat!
export server_node2=`cat ~/tomar2.log`
```

Comment: I don't think that the logfile is executable ;-) . Also, the OP poster wants to store the *content* of the log file into the variable (which is strange, but let us hope that he knows what he is doing here).

Comment: Sorry, I had a copy/paste issue and added the missing `cat`s

Answer (score -1):

There are several possibilities. In your case, you could on the remote system create a file (in bash syntax), containing the assignments of these variables, for example

```
echo "export server_node2='$(</home/rt9419/tomar.log)'" >>export_settings
```

(which makes me wonder why you want the whole content of your logfile be stored into a variable, but this is another question), then transfer this file to your host (for example with scp) and source it from within your bash script.

Comment: Then why not simply copy the log file directly, and take it from there?  If the log file contained a single quote anywhere, this would break because of that, and otherwise, too, seems rather brittle.